# CSS Menu - phantom effect on dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, menu

http://immlawyer.wpengine.com/

This makes no sense. When you rollover the homepage image UNDER the "OUR SERVICES" menu choice, the dropdown menu appears. Even more confusing, if you roll over the third guy on the right, the dropdown menu appears. The drop down should ONLY appear when you rollover the "Our Services" area.  Why is the whole area underneath causing the menu to appear?

NB: I had asked another question about the menu, but was able to resolve that issue.  Thanks.

HTML:

```
<span class="menu_control">≡</span>
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-8 current_page_item menu-item-20">
<li id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-21">
<li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-24">
<a href="http://immlawyer.wpengine.com/our-services/">Our Services</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-68" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-68">
<li id="menu-item-64" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-64">
<li id="menu-item-74" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-74">
<li id="menu-item-72" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-72">
<li id="menu-item-66" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-66">
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.menu .menu-item-has-children a::after {
    top: 10px;
}
.menu .sub-menu a {
    border-bottom: 0 dotted #dddddd;
    border-left-width: 0;
}
.menu .sub-menu a {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #dddddd;
    border-left-width: 1px;
}
.menu a {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-width: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.menu, .menu a, .menu .sub-menu {
    border-color: #dddddd;
}
.menu a {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 1px 0 0;
    color: #111111;
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 0.75em 1em;
    text-transform: none;
}
.menu a, .menu_control {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 0;
    color: #111111;
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 0.75em 1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.lato-text, body, body a {
    font-family: "Lato",sans-serif;
}
a, a:hover, .mm-button p, .mm-button:hover p, .sidebar #searchsubmit, .sidebar #searchsubmit:hover {
    transition: all 0.5s linear 0s;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the page, you seem to be just setting the opacity to zero on the drop down menu items. This only makes them transparent, however they still take up space so can be hovered over. That is why if you hover over where any of them are they appear.

You probably need to have them set as `display:none` until the parent is hovered over.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what is happening here is that there is a lot of hidden li's and ul's that are hidden and when are hovered over, pop up. So, because they are hidden and all that it takes is a mouse-over event for them to display, they show up.